# Get the minimum value over a window and add it to all values in window PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a sql table that contains 2 columns date and value (there are actually more and I am performing partition by clauses, however for sake of the example, I think the simpler explanation will suffice).

The table looks as such:
| date | value |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 |
| 2019-01-02 | 2 |
| 2019-01-03 | 3 |
| 2019-01-04 | 4 |
| 2019-01-05 | 5 |
| 2019-01-06 | 6 |

I want to find the minimum value over the last 3 periods in the value column and add it to each of the previous 3 values in the value column (i.e., the values in the rolling window). For example, starting from the first window, the window would contain values 1,2,3 and the minimum value would be 1. Thus, I want to add 1 to 1,2,3 so the first the rows in the value column would be 2, 3, 4. Starting from the second window the window would contain values 2,3,4 and the minimum value would be 2 so I would like 2,3,4 to become 4, 5, 6.

As you can see in from the example these values needed to be updated on the fly (I am thinking a function) because old values can be overwritten if the minimum changes.

Is there any way to pass a window function to a function in postgres?

In python I handle this situation as such:

```
def adjust_data(data):
    return [x + abs(min(data)) for x in data]
```

which returns a list of the adjusted numbers I want. I am passing the values over a rolling window using `df['value'].rolling(4).apply(adjust_data)`.

I am looking for the same SQL based solution. Goes without saying but any words of the wise would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I can clear up any of the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add min to the MIN of value in the group with the following query:

```
SELECT 
 date,
 value, 
 value + (MIN(value) 
          OVER(ORDER BY date, value 
          ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS adj_value
FROM t;
```

If the "window" is just blocks of three rows, then I think you can use integer division on the row number to create the blocks, and then partition by the block id and add the min, something like the query below:

```
WITH blk AS (
 SELECT 
  date,
  value, 
  DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date, value), 4) AS blkid
 FROM t;
)

SELECT
  date,
  value,
  value + MIN(value) OVER(PARTITION BY blkid) AS adj_value
FROM blk
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your quick response. However, this does nor properly fix the problem in the question. Following this logic, window two (2,3,4) in the example above would have min values of (1,1,2). So the result would be (2+1, 3+1, 4+2). Whereas, I would like all of window two to be (2+2, 3+2, 4+2) e.g., the minimum value in each individual window. It's a tricky problem and I could have done a better job explaining it.